# Session cookie doesnt seem to be included

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

Im trying to pass the user email to another controller but cant get Session["Email"] to work. I have tried to include system.web.mvc but this also doent change anything.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session;
using RestSharp;
using Temzih.Models;
using TemzihLogic;

    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register_Volunteer(Register_User Register)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //volunteer.Register(Register.Email, Register.Firstname, Register.Lastname, Register.Password);
                Session["Email"] = Register.Email;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "EmailConfirm", cookie);
            }

            else
            {
                return View("Index_Volunteer", new Register_User());
            }



        }
```

Comment: you can use TempData

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and I presume you are "loosing" the value (aka it is NULL), you can use

```
TempData["Email"] = Register.Email; 
TempData.Keep();
```

To keep this in "memory".

Comment: @im_Ruben, have you fixed your issue?